# how do you put a line into an array in php

Tags: php

I have a $line like below in php

```
33 0 0 51037280 396822 15 16 0 0 0 0 20907 143197 57377 27 12 51 10 7.33 45.8 17:07:31
```

I try to create and array and put each value seperated by space to this array like this:

```
$parts=explode(" ", $line)
```

there should be 20 indexes, there are 21 coluns on this $line. But when I do this:

```
   $size=sizeof($parts)
```

echo $size returns 58, how is this possible. Is there any better way to insert to items in $line to an array? Looks like there irregular amount of spaces between values. when I do this:

print_r($parts)

I get the following:

```
[0] => [1] => 33 [2] => [3] => [4] => 0 [5] => [6] => [7] => 0 [8] => [9] => [10] => 51037280 [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => 396822 [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => 15 [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => 16 [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => 0 [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => 0 [34] => [35] => [36] => [37] => [38] => 0 [39] => [40] => [41] => [42] => [43] => [44] => 0 [45] => 20907 [46] => 143197 [47] => 57377 [48] => 27 [49] => 12 [50] => 51 [51] => 10 [52] => [53] => 7.33 [54] => [55] => 45.8 [56] => 17:07:31 )
```

How would I ignore the number of spaces between the values and store each value as an array value in php?

Comment: what does a `var_dump($parts)` show? if there truly were 21 columns in there, you'd get a count of 21. so check out what you're ACTUALLY getting.

Comment: You might want to check that your code actually reproduces your issue: `echo (sizeof(explode(" ", "35 0 0 51020880 462460 6 23 0 0 0 0 21770 142334 67212 31 12 46 11 8.13 50.8 16:07:29 58"))); # 22`

Comment: The code as you posted, works perfectly fine, I tested in http://writecodeonline.com/php/  and its working perfectly....returns 22

Comment: probably he pasted it from the browser and it's collapsing down multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there's only one space between elements, there are not whitespaces in the start or end of string and then split the string:

```
 $line = trim($line);
 $line = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $line);
 $parts=explode(" ", $line)
```

Comment: when do your suggestion and perform print_r($parts), I get this:  Array ( [0] => [1] => 31 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 51012972 [5] => 397817 [6] => 14 [7] => 26 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 18863 [13] => 146092 [14] => 56330 [15] => 23 [16] => 11 [17] => 56 [18] => 10 [19] => 6.50 [20] => 40.6 [21] => 17:22:31 )

Comment: @user1471980 I've updated the example to avoid whitespaces in the starting or ending of string

Comment: I had to use trim() function to remove beginning and training spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are occurance of multiple spaces together.

try

```
 $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
```

Comment: `\s+` instead of `\s\s*`?

Comment: I copied the line directly from his post, and it worked as is, returned 22,.....so while that may be the issue, if the data he provided is real....then its not

Comment: @Orangepill, is your syntax right?

Comment: @user1471980 Shouldbe now that barmar set me straight :)

Comment: The fact that elements 0, 2,3, etc are empty strings pretty much confirms my suspicions

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out empty strings later on, but easier would be to do this:

```
preg_split('/ +/',$string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: @KyleK: look at his data in the `print_r`. While he may have copy/pasted his input from a web-context, making all spaces run together, the `print_r` clearly shows there are multiple spaces.